# Bind to Code Behind Property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, properties, code-behind

I am looking to bind to a property in my code-behind.  So far what I have found doesn't exactly help me but it has gotten me to where I am.

What I am trying to do is bind a `bool` to a `DataTrigger` so that I may set an "*" next to the folder name when a table inside has been edited, indicating that saving is now an option.  I know that my event handling is set up correctly because when I debug the property is the value I wish it to be.

From everything I've seen this should work but most examples were related to setting text.  Here's the code-block containing the binding for reference:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:EditableDatabaseNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="Resources\db.png" Style="{StaticResource tvImage}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Name="tb_modfied" Text=""/>
    </StackPanel>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=IsChanged}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="tb_modfied" Property="Text" Value="*"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

It's line 8 of the code block I'm having trouble with in case you were unable to deduce it.

Edit: In case, like me, you're too lazy to read comments.  The property is a public property in my code behind.  As for binding related errors there is a `NullReferenceException` because the binding is not hooking to anything

Here is what exactly my error says:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'IsChanged' value (type 'Boolean') from '' (type 'MainWindow'). BindingExpression:Path=IsChanged; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'ContentPresenter' (Name='PART_Header'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you show any related binding errors? Is "IsChanged" a public property on your code-behind?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET IsChanged indeed is a public property in my code-behind.  The binding related error is a NullReferenceException because it's not binding to anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems here.

First off, you need to remove the `Text=""` from your `<TextBlock>` tag

Properties defined within the `<Tag>` itself take precedence over any Triggered values, so the value will not change.

You can read more about it on [MSDN's page on Dependency Property Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx#listing)

---

Second problem is the binding in your Trigger itself.

It is set to

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=IsChanged}"
```

Which means *"go backwards up the visual tree until you find the first `Window` object, and check the `IsChanged` property"*. Except I'm pretty sure the Window class does not have a property called IsChanged.

You are most likely looking to bind to the DataContext of the current item, so your binding should look something like

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChanged}" Value="True">
```

Comment: You're right, I just needed to move where my property originally was to my DataContext. Thanks!